# Having an issue with ascertaining the format of a date

Tags: date, formatting

I've been tasked with getting data from an existing database table and transferring it into another. Everything is fine except the date in the original table is in a format that I don't recognise. It looks suspiciously like a unix timestamp but when converting it it seems to be coming out as the year 2727 or something.

Here is an example of what's in the existing table: `1424786878240`

The matching date for this on the front end of the site is 24th February 2015. I cannot seem to find any correlation between this and the number in the database - and since I have no access to the original site code I am unable to determine how it's being converted.

If anyone recognises this date format / structure I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Its a unix timestamp in *milliseconds*, so divide by 1000 to treat it as seconds.

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of that! That's exactly it, thank you very much!